# Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb R$

Tags: compactifications, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

Let $\beta X$ - is a Stone-Čech compactification of $X$. $I=(-1,1)$ - is an interval of the real line. Is it true that $\beta \mathbb R\setminus I = \beta(\mathbb R\setminus I)$? In other words, it means that a finite interval does not affect on the "compactification of infinity".

**Update**:
Great thanks for realized calculations.

Comment: People are already voting to close... It might help if you could say what you have tried?  What's your definition of the Stone-Cech compactification?  Do you have a start of a proof of the claim, but that you get stuck somewhere?  What's your motivation?

Comment: I think this is a good question. If $I$ is closed, then $\mathbb R\setminus I $ is homeomorphic to two copies of $\mathbb R$, so the answer is no (same for the half-closed case). If $I$ is open, it feels like the answer should be yes ... it would be necessary to show that $I$ remains open in $\beta\mathbb R$, which seems right, but Stone-Cech compactifications are weird and I don't see that right now.

Comment: "same" means similar argument, not that $\mathbb R\setminus I\cong \mathbb R\sqcup \mathbb R$.

Comment: I should add that I haven't voted to close-- but the person who did hasn't given a reason...  

Comment: I wonder why 'stone-cech' wasn't an existing tag?


Comment: @Anton: If $I$ is closed then continuous (complex valued) functions on $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$ do not extend to continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. They do when $I$ is the open interval.

Comment: @Mariarty: I think it would be better to ask your "update" as a new question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can show the following (which Anton was asking about in comments).  Let $X$ be locally compact and Hausdorff, and $U\subseteq X$ open.  Let $X_\infty$ be the one-point compactication, so $U$ is still open in $X_\infty$.  By the universal property of the Stone-Cech compactification, there is a continuous map $\phi:\beta X\rightarrow X_\infty$ which is the identity on $X$.  Then $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\beta X$, and is just the canonical image of $U$ in $\beta X$.  So $U$ open in $X$ shows that $U$ is open in $\beta X$.

(This fails for general closed sets.  If $F\subseteq X$ is closed, then $F$ is only closed in $X_\infty$ if $F$ is also compact.)

I'll now use that $\beta X$ is the character space of $C^b(X)$.  Let $U\subseteq X$ be open.

> Lemma: Assume that $U$ is relatively compact.  Under the isomorphism $C(\beta X)=C^b(X)$, we identify the ideal $\{ f\in C(\beta X) : f(x)=0 \ (x\not\in U) \}$ with $\{ F\in C^b(X) : f(x)=0 \ (x\not\in U) \}$
>
> Proof: $X$ is itself open in $\beta X$, and the image of $C_0(X)$ in $C(\beta X)$ is just the functions vanishing off $X$.  If $F\in C^b(X)$ vanishes off $U$ then $F\in C_0(X)$ (as $U$ is relatively compact) and so the associated $f$ in $C(\beta X)$ vanishes off $U$.  Conversely, if $f\in C(\beta X)$ vanishes off $U$ then the associated $F\in C^b(X)$ is just the restriction of $f$ to $X$, and so vanishes off $U$.

By the Tietze theorem, the restriction map $C(\beta X) \rightarrow C(\beta X \setminus U)$ is a surjection.  So we can identify $C(\beta X\setminus U)$ with the quotient $C(\beta X) / \{ f\in C(\beta X) : f(x)=0 \ (x\not\in U) \}$.  So by the above, we identify $C(\beta X \setminus U)$ with $C^b(X) / \{ F\in C^b(X) : F(x)=0 \ (x\not\in U) \}$.  If $X$ is normal, then we can again use Tietze to extend any $F\in C^b(X\setminus U)$ to all of $X$.  It follows that $C^b(X) / \{ F\in C^b(X) : F(x)=0 \ (x\not\in U) \}$ is isomorphic to $C^b(X\setminus U) = C(\beta(X\setminus U))$.  So $\beta X \setminus U = \beta (X\setminus U)$ (in a fairly canonical way) under the hypotheses that $X$ is normal and $U$ is relatively compact.

(I'm not sure what happens for non-normal $X$.  For $X=\mathbb R$ and $U$ an open interval, we obviously don't need Tietze.)

Comment: In some sense this is nothing but a careful elaboration of George Lowther's hint!

Comment: So, why doesn't this argument also work for $U=X$?

Comment: I think $U$ is implicitly assumed relatively compact:  "... then $F\in C_0(X)$" 

Comment: I think $C(\beta X\setminus U)$ should be identified with $C_b(X)/C_0(U)$.

Comment: @George, @BS: I've added the hypothesis that U is relatively compact. Thanks!  George's 2nd comment is what's works for general $U$; and so I guess if $U$ isn't relatively compact, then $\beta X\setminus U$ is not $\beta(X\setminus U)$.

Comment: So $\beta X\setminus U=\beta(X\setminus U)$ for all locally compact $X$ and relatively compact open $U$. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

More generally: if $X$ is normal and $A$ is closed in $X$ then, by the Tietze-Urysohn theorem, the closure in $\beta X$ of $A$ *is* $\beta A$. In the example above $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{R} \setminus (-1,1)$. 
As the closure of $(-1,1)$ in $\beta\mathbb{R}$ is just $[-1,1]$ the desired equality follows.